# What's the difference between functions starting with G_ and GTK_?

Tags: gtk

I am currently trying to learn about GTK from the documentation. However, I am unsure about a slight difference.

`G_APPLICATION(app)` and
`GTK_APPLICATION(app)`.

or

`gtk_application_window_new` and 
`g_signal_connect`.

So, when is the G used instead of GTK? It's probably a pathetic question but is it to do with GTK being a widget library and adopting a few things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`G_` functions come from GLib, a general-purpose utility library. `GTK_` functions come from Gtk+, GUI toolkit based on Glib.

So anything not directly related to GUI (e.g. data structures, signal handling) is part of Glib, whereas GUI bits (windows, buttons etc) are part of Gtk+. Because of that, it's possible to use features provided by Glib outside GUI, for example in console and server applications.

There seems to be some overlap, such as beforementioned `GApplication`/`GtkApplication`, but the same rule holds: `GApplication` forms basis of `GtkApplication`, where general bits are handled by the former, and GUI-related bits are handled by the latter.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought that was the case.